# Необходимо удалить строки с соответствующими ID

Tags: mysql, python

В mysql есть таблица.
Есть список

```
outcoming = [445557378, 54667402, 11365645, 52258043, 332914832, 357652627, 276344229, 170537256, 480499887, 226384949, 81816373, 230656439, 164630458, 178836923, 310206267, 155180221, 264821829, 2146377, 170161869, 91485777, 64653010, 229433813, 277918294, 436511322, 63895647, 171503843, 56553574, 429354732, 61759727, 122231536, 442422643, 426659704, 317070969, 52351738, 192707195, 24703613]
```

необходимо из таблицы удалить строки, в которых `user_id` равно каждому из элементов списка.

Я написал вот такой код:

```
    import mysql.connector

    database = mysql.connector.connect(user=settings.db_login, password=settings.db_password,
                                           host=settings.dp_ip, database=settings.db_name, use_unicode=True,
                                           charset='utf8', collation='utf8_general_ci', autocommit=True)
        cursor = database.cursor()
cursor.execute("""DELETE from list_of_tables WHERE user_id = (%s)""", (outcoming))
```

Я попробовал вот так:

```
for user_id in outcoming:
        cursor.execute("""DELETE from list_of_users WHERE user_id = (%s)""", (user_id))
```

Но что-то не получилось

Comment: насколько большим (сколько элементов) может быть список `outcoming` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заверните в цикл:

```
for id in outcoming:
    cursor.execute("""DELETE from list_of_tables WHERE user_id = (%s)""", (id))
```

Comment: После “id” надо поставить запятую: (id,)

Comment: Вредный совет..

Comment: @andreymal Дайте полезный.

Comment: Не могу, я сам знаю только вредные :( Но это не значит, что их стоит писать

Comment: @andreymal Ну хотя бы расскажите, почему вредный.

Comment: Ну хотя бы потому, что это всё можно объединить в один `WHERE user_id IN (чтототам)`, а при включенном автокоммите ваш вариант просто будет жутко медленным (в запущенных случаях — по полсекунды на каждый user_id, например)

Comment: @andreymal Так это не вредный, а медленный. Вредный это если бы он базу портил или бы давал возможность для взлома. Если можно ``WHERE user_id IN (чтототам)`` и это еще и быстрее, то я только за :)

Comment: @Эникейщик [А потом скрипты, которые должны отрабатывать за минуту, работают несколько суток, ага](https://habrahabr.ru/post/352688/)

Answer (score 2):

Если список параметров не очень большой, скажем до 100 элементов, то можно использовать конструкцию `... WHERE user_id IN (?, ?, ?)`, т.е. параметризовать SQL запрос:

```
q = """DELETE from list_of_users user_id IN ({})""".format(','.join(['?'] * len(outcoming)))
cursor.execute(q, outcoming)
```

`q` будет выглядеть так:

```
In [5]: q
Out[5]: 'DELETE from list_of_users WHERE user_id IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
```

---

Если же список параметров содержит много элементов, то эффективнее будет загрузить эти ID's во временную таблицу и использовать подзапрос:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
import pandas as pd

conn = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://mysql_user:mysql_password@mysql_host/mysql_db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(user_id=outcoming))

df.to_sql('tmp_user_id', conn, if_exists='replace')

cursor.execute("DELETE FROM list_of_users WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM tmp_user_id)")
```